# $(this) in timeout (again)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the nice `animate.css` I would like to animate with a `pulse` animation all the elements in the class `pulsating` on a `hover` event. The animation should stop when the mouse pointer leaves the element.

The following code works:

```
$('.pulsating').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(
        function() {$(this).addClass('animated infinite pulse');},
        function() {$(this).removeClass('animated infinite pulse');}
        ); // hover
}); // each .pulsating
```

However I would like the transition to continue for a bit when the mouse goes away. So, after some attempts and a search here, I implemented this function:

```
$('.pulsating').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(
        function() {$(this).addClass('animated infinite pulse');},
        function() {var el=$(this); window.setTimeout(function(){el.removeClass('animated infinite pulse');}, 2000);} 
        ); // hover
}); // each .pulsating
```

As you can see I keep a reference to `$(this)` but it does not work: the hovered elements keep pulsating ad infinitum.

Comment: That looks like it should work just fine. You can ditch the call to `.each` and directly call `.hover` on the selected elements. Please create a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Agreeing with Felix, seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8sJ7R/ . I added the extra `timeout` stuff (and kept the `.each()` because of it) to allow for syncing of the timeout per element...otherwise things can get weird if you hover in and out quickly (quicker than your timeout)